# react-native calling custom view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a custom `header` view and I have call this inside my class but for some reason it is not showing.

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

customHeader(){
       <View style={{height:80, width:'100%', backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
           <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text>Header</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
}

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
//Calling my custom header
        {this.customHeader()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I feel like my code is correct but the header is not showing. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `customHeader` function must **return** something. Right now it just runs jsx and returns nothing. Fix it like this for example:

```
customHeader(){
  return (
    <View style={{height:80, width:'100%', backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>Header</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```